# Does Brownian Motion return to the origin infinitely soon?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Consider a standard unidimensional Brownian Motion $B_t$ (Wiener process).

Fact: This process returns to the origin infinite number of times with probability one.

Consider a stopping time $\tau = \inf \{t>0: B_t=0 \}$ (time of the first return).

Question: what can we say about the distribution of $\tau$?
In particular, is it true that $\forall t >0$: $\Pr(\tau < t)=1$, i.e. BM almost surely returns to the origin infinitely soon?

Comment: Yes; the set of zeros of a Wiener trajectory forms a perfect set almost surely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C_t = \dfrac{B_{at}}{\sqrt{a}}$.  Then $C_t$ has the same distribution as $B_t$ and for $0<t_1<\cdots<t_n$, $(C_{t_1},\ldots,C_{t_n})$ has the same distribution as $(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n})$.

$C_t=0$ if and only if $B_{at}=0$.  Thus rescaling the set of all returns to $0$ results in a set of all returns to $0$ that has the same probability distribution.

Comment: Is this supposed to prove that $\tau=0$ almost surely?

Comment: Yes, it just lacks the last step. This argument implies in particular that the distribution of $\tau$ is described by cdf $F_\tau (t)=const$ for $t>0$. Since $\lim _{t\to\infty} F_\tau (t)=1$, we get $F_\tau (t)=1$ $\forall t>0$.